# Spring-Boot : DevTools doesn't refresh files

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, devtools

I use STS for build a webserver.

I put dependency in pom.xml with this code

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        <optional>true</optional>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

When I run my Webserver with IDE (Spring Tool Suite), if 'html' file which will shown on browser changes, it automatically apply changes.

but if I run it as standalone ( 'mvnw spring-boot:run' ) it doesn't work.

how can I fix this problem?

Currently work with Springframework.boot 2.0.4.RELEASE

Answer (score 1):

In application.properties set:

```
spring.devtools.restart.exclude=
```

Default value is (maybe your html file is here):

```
spring.devtools.restart.exclude=META-INF/maven/**,META-INF/resources/**,resources/**,static/**,public/**,templates/**,**/*Test.class,**/*Tests.class,git.properties
```

Comment: unfortunately, it doesn't work. anyways, thanks for your advise.